# Delete Method of Range Class Failed when trying to delete table rows

Tags: excel, vba

I busted my head and couldn't figure out why I'm getting the this error...

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela6").Range.AutoFilter Field:=164, Criteria1:= _
    "Não"
With Worksheets("Thundera").AutoFilter.Range
   Range("FH" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).EntireRow.Select
End With
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

I really am in a dead end... Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary selects. What happens if you just use the line `ActiveSheet.Range("FH" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Do you want deleting the table (`ListObject`) rows or the sheet rows? As stated above, none of used selections are necessary. I have a supposition, but looking to your code I cannot dare to think I understood what you want. Can you explain **in words** what you try doing?

Comment: @dbmitch it only delete the first row and I need all of then...

Comment: @FaneDuru I'm trying to apply I filter then deleting all the visible rows it shows... Entire table row

Comment: Entire table row is not the same with sheet row. So, what do you want deleting, **from this point of view**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try using the next way(s). I asked about what you really need deleting but you did not answer... So I prepared an answer for both possibilities:

1. The next code deletes the TABLE rows:

```
Sub DeleteTableRows() 
  Dim tbl As ListObject
  
   Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela6")
   tbl.Range.AutoFilter field:=164, Criteria1:="Não"
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

2. This one deletes the SHEET rows by TABLE visible cells:

```
Sub DeleteSheetRows() 
  Dim tbl As ListObject
  
   Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela6")
   tbl.Range.AutoFilter field:=164, Criteria1:="Não"
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).rows.Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry the delay to answer but it worked like a charm!!! Solution 1 was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!!!